# Passing an unknown number of arguments into ParamArray in VBA

Tags: vba, paramarray

I have a function that takes in a `ParamArray` that I'm trying to pass an unknown number of parameters into. I'm looping through rows and passing in numbers based on if the cells are empty or not, but it seems like I have to pass in each number as its own argument. I tried putting the numbers into an array and passing that, but it just ended up being an array of an array in the function and not working properly. Is there a way to do this?

Ex:

```vb
Dim myarray() as double

Function test(ParamArray arg() as Variant) as Single
  'function does stuff with arg(s)
End Function
```

```vb
For Each cell in [somerange]
  If cell <> "" then
    'save cell value into an myarray?
  End If
Next

'want to pass those saved values into function
Call test(myarray)
```

Edit: I kind of found a workaround. I realized I can pass a range into the function so I'm just going to create a temporary range and pass that in.

Comment: I'm visual, can you please add a little code snippet to illustrate your problem?

Answer (score 2):

From Cpearson [Passing And Returning Arrays With Functions](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/passingandreturningarrays.htm), this is how you pass an array into a function and loop that array:

```
Sub DoSomethingWithPassedArray(ByRef Arr() As Long)

    Dim N As Long
    For N = LBound(Arr) To UBound(Arr)
        '...do something
    Next N
End Sub
```

Further on, it's not clear what you want to do...

Answer (score 0):

Here it is (it is related with my question in [Calling vba macro from python with unknown number of arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188684/calling-vba-macro-from-python-with-unknown-number-of-arguments))

Use this:

```vb
Sub pass_this()
    Call flexible("a")
End Sub
Sub pass_alsothis()
    Call flexible("a", 2)
End Sub
Sub flexible(ParamArray args() As Variant)
    Dim i As Long
    MsgBox ("I have received " & _
            Str(UBound(args) + 1) & _
            " parameters.")
    For i = 0 To UBound(args)
        MsgBox (TypeName(args(i)))
    Next i
End Sub
```

Cheers.