# Form new lists from elements in an existing list and assign a worksheet name

Tags: python, list, dictionary, variables

The title may sound confusing...but this is what I need to do:

I have a list (which will be variable in length, with different values depending on various scenarios), e.g: list1 = ['backup', 'downloadMedia', 'createAlbum']. From this list, I need to create one of the following for each of these items: (and obviously the name will update depending on the item in the list)

1. I need to create a new list called: testcases_backup = []
2. I need to create a new list called: results_backup = []
3. I need to create a new list called: screenshot_paths_backup = []
4. And lastly, I need to open a new worksheet, which requires: worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results'). Of note in this case, I will need to iterate 1,2,3,... for the worksheet name for each of the items in the list. So for the first iteration for 'backup', it will be worksheet1. and 2 for downloadMedia, etc.

I have tried using dictionaries, but at this point I am not making any real progress.

My attempt: (I have very limited exp with dictionaries)

```
master_test_list = ['backup', 'downloadMedia', 'createAlbum']
master_test_dict = {}
def addTest(test, worksheet, testcases_list, results_list, screenshots_path_list):
    master_test_dict[test] = worksheet
    master_test_dict[test] = testcases_list
    master_test_dict[test] = results_list
    master_test_dict[test] = screenshots_path_list

for test in master_test_list:
    addTest(test, "worksheet"+str(master_test_list.index(test)+1), "testcases_list_"+test, "results_list_"+test, "screenshots_path_list_"+test)
    
print(results_list_backup)
```

I thought this might work...but I just get strings inside the lists, and so I cannot define them as lists:

```
worksheets = []
for i in range(len(master_test_list)):
    worksheets.append(str(i+1))
worksheets = ["worksheet%s" % x for x in worksheets]
testcases = ["testcases_list_%s" % x for x in master_test_list]
results = ["results_%s" % x for x in master_test_list]
screenshot_paths = ["screenshot_paths_%s" % x for x in master_test_list]

for w in worksheets:
    w = workbook.add_worksheet('Results')
for t in testcases:
    t = []
for r in results:
    r = []
for s in screenshot_paths:
    s = []
```

Comment: this looks like a pseudo code so far, pls post the code and shows your attempt.

Comment: I posted whatever I came up with, which does not work. I do not have much of any experience with dictionaries...

Comment: can anyone help with this? even just point me in the right direction. I get the dictionary idea a little more now...but I am not understanding how that will allow me form a list that I will continually append throughout my script.

Comment: essentially this is what I need:
1. create n copies of 3 lists, depending on the len of list1.
2. create n worksheets by using worksheet_i = workbook.add_worksheet('Results').

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding a second answer since the code is significantly different, addressing the specified request for how to create n copies of lists:

```
def GenerateElements():
    # Insert your code which generates your list here
    myGeneratedList = ['backup', 'downloadMedia', 'createAlbum']
    return myGeneratedList


def InitDict(ListOfElements):
    # Dont make a new free floating list for each element of list1. Generate and store the lists you want in a dictionary
    return dict([[x, []] for x in ListOfElements])


def RunTest():
    for myContent in list1:
        # Do whatever you like to generate the data u need
        myTestCaseList = ['a', 'b']
        myResultsList = [1, 2]
        myScreenshot_Paths_List = ['sc1', 'sc2']

        # 1 Store your created list for test case of item 'myContent' from list1 in a dictionary
        testcases[myContent].append(myTestCaseList)
        # 2 Same but your results list
        results[myContent].append(myResultsList)
        # 3 Same but your screenshot_paths list
        screenshot_paths[myContent].append(myScreenshot_Paths_List)
        # 4 Make an excel sheet named after the item from list1
        # run_vba_macro("C:\\Users\\xx-_-\\Documents\\Coding Products\\Python (Local)\\Programs\\Python X Excel\\AddSheets.xlsm","SheetAdder", "AddASheet", myContent)


list1 = GenerateElements()
testcases, results, screenshot_paths = InitDict(
    list1), InitDict(list1), InitDict(list1)

NumTests = 5  # Number of tests you want
for x in range(NumTests):
    RunTest()
```

What's going on here is just defining some initialization functions and then exercising them in a couple of lines.

My understanding is that you are running a series of tests, where you want a list of the inputs and outputs to be a running tally kind of thing. As such, this code uses a dictionary to store a list of lists. The dictionary key is how you identify which log you're looking at: test cases log vs results log vs screenshot_paths log.

As per my understanding of your requirements, each dictionary element is a list of lists where the 1st list is just the output of the first test. The second list is the first with the outcome of the second test/result appended to it. This goes on, so the structure looks like:

```
testcases= [ [testcase1] , [testcase1,testcase2] , [testcase1,testcase2,testcase3] ]
```

etc.

If this isn't exactly what you want you can probably modify it to suit your needs.

Comment: Honestly I think I went too far off the deep end in terms of trying to read between the lines and make a lot of assumptions about your structure and goal and what not. I can't spend any more time on this for now. If what you're trying to do is to use Excel as a repository for some kind of testing log, You might really want to reconsider using the module you mentioned, and just use some kind of CSV structure. Hard to say more without better understanding of your goals. If you want a better response I recommend overhauling the question, succinctly defining inputs/outputs, objective, & reasoning

Comment: I appreciate your efforts very much. thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

You explanation leaves some things to be imagined, but I think I've got what you need. There are two files: The .py python file and an excel file which is the spreadsheet serving as a foundation for adding sheets. You can find the ones I made on my github:

https://github.com/DavidD003/LearningPython

here is the excel code. Sharing first because its shorter. If you don't want to download mine then make a sheet called 'AddSheets.xlsm' with a module called 'SheetAdder' and within that module put the following code:

```
Public Sub AddASheet(nm)
    
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False 'Reset on workbook open event, since we need it to be False here right up to the point of saving and closing
    
    Dim NewSheet As Worksheet
    
    Set NewSheet = ThisWorkbook.Sheets.Add
    NewSheet.Name = nm
    
End Sub
```

Make sure to add this to the 'ThisWorkbook' code in the 'MicroSoft Excel Objects' folder of the VBA project:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

The python script is as follows:

See [this question][1] for an example of how to type format the filepath as a string for function argument. I removed mine here.

````
import win32com.client as wincl
import os

# Following modified from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188684/calling-vba-macro-from-python-with-unknown-number-of-arguments


def run_vba_macro(str_path, str_modulename, str_macroname, shtNm):
    if os.path.exists(str_path):
        xl = wincl.DispatchEx("Excel.Application")
        wb = xl.Workbooks.Open(str_path, ReadOnly=0)
        xl.Visible = True
        xl.Application.Run(os.path.basename(str_path)+"!" +
                           str_modulename+'.'+str_macroname, shtNm)
        wb.Save()
        wb.Close()
        xl.Application.Quit()
        del xl


# Insert your code which generates your list here
list1 = ['backup', 'downloadMedia', 'createAlbum']

# Dont make a new free floating list for each element of list1. Generate and store the lists you want in a dictionary
testcases = dict([[x, []] for x in list1])
results = dict([[x, []] for x in list1])
screenshot_paths = dict([[x, []] for x in list1])

for myContent in list1:
    myTestCaseList = []  # Do whatever you like to generate the data u need
    myResultsList = []
    myScreenshot_Paths_List = []

    # 1 Store your created list for test case of item 'myContent' from list1 in a dictionary
    testcases[myContent].append(myTestCaseList)
    # 2 Same but your results list
    results[myContent].append(myResultsList)
    # 3 Same but your screenshot_paths list
    screenshot_paths[myContent].append(myScreenshot_Paths_List)
    # 4 Make an excel sheet named after the item from list1
    run_vba_macro("C:\\Users\\xx-_-\\Documents\\Coding Products\\Python (Local)\\Programs\\Python X Excel\\AddSheets.xlsm",
                  "SheetAdder", "AddASheet", myContent)```

I started working on this before you updated your question with a code sample, so bear in mind I haven't looked at your code at all lol. Just ran with this. 

Here is a summary of what all of the above does:
-Creates an excel sheet with a sheet for every element in 'list1', with the sheet named after that element
-Generates 3 dictionaries, one for test cases, one for results, and one for screenshot paths, where each dictionary has a list for each element from 'list1', with that list as the value for the key being the element in 'list1'


  [1]: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58188684/calling-vba-macro-from-python-with-unknown-number-of-arguments
````

Comment: thank you for the awesome answer. Unfortunately, I need to stick with how I currently handle excel files using the xlsxwriter python module. As for the bottom part where you handle the dictionary, my script will be very long and I will be continually appending the results/testcase/screenshot lists, will this method still work?

Comment: Essentially I need n copies of a list, with a name set by the list1 elements, that will remain open the entire test that I will continually be adding to.

Comment: yeah, understood. Essentially, the point of even mentioning the excel stuff and xlsxwriter is that I need a way to define: worksheet1/2/3/4/5/6 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results')...where the number of workbooks I define (either 1,2,3,4,5,6,...) is variable.

Comment: Dont worksheets automatically get iteratively named? (Worksheet1,Worksheet2, etc). Couldn't you leave them named as that to save the headache?

Comment: no the naming comes when I define it, e.g:
worksheet1 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results')
worksheet2 = workbook.add_worksheet('Results')


essentially this is what I need: 1. create n copies of 3 lists, depending on the len of list1. 2. create n worksheets by using worksheet_i = workbook.add_worksheet('Results').